# how to map a request object data that can have different types and extends from another class?

Tags: java, rest, inheritance, jackson, soapui

Hello everyone and thanks for the help.

lets say I have:

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/endpoint")
public A createA(A a);
```

Model A:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = IndividualParty.class, name = "B"), 
  @Type(value = CorporateParty.class, name = "C") 
})
public class A {

private String id;
private String description;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

**Model B and C extends Model A**. and they have different fields.

**I have the request and reponse models too**. The request is made with a **A** object.

Im using the jackson inheritance annotations and I use soapUI to create the **body**.
so, when I debug I can actually see if the type is B or C.

The probrem is, in the class that I receive the request I only have access to the A fields and I cant map the data to the api that way, I need to have access to the B and C fields, but the request model only has the A object to do the request, but since B and C extends A I should be able to do it right?
for example:

```
public returnType method(CreateARequest request){}
```

What I want to do here is to map the request I made in the soapUI(body) to others fields that are in another place.

for example: someOtherRequest.SetName(request.getName());

this request can be B or C but I only have access to the A fields...
Even if I do request.SetA(new B());
and then Request.getA().
its the same result...

any idea??? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.
I can't try it because I dont have remote access right now so, there is no way for me to know for sure but I think it was simple if I do a simple downcast:

B b = new B();

b = (B)request.getA();

and now I should be able to map the data right?